# Do I have a logic issue?

Tags: c

```
contact entry = {"", "", "", ""};

while (choice == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4){  
    if (choice == 1){
        printf ("First name: \n");    
        fgets(entry.firstname, sizeof(entry.firstname),stdin); 
        break;
    }
    else if(choice == 2){
        printf ("Last name: \n");     
        fgets(entry.lastname, sizeof(entry.lastname),stdin); 
        break;
    }
    else if(choice == 3){
        printf ("Address: \n");   
        fgets(entry.address, sizeof(entry.address),stdin); 
        break;
    }
    else if (choice == 4){
        printf ("Phone number: \n");      
        fgets(entry.phone, sizeof(entry.phone),stdin); 
        break;
    }
    else{
        printf("Exiting");
        return 0;
    }
}

fwrite (&entry, sizeof (contact), 1, pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

This is the code I have. It seems simple enough and I've traced it following it if I press 1,2,3, or 4 . So it knows which if ,else if, else body to go to but it seems to exit really quickly as well as not write what I want it to to the file. Any obvious mistakes here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I changed while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 4){   to  while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 4){ , but I still have an issue with nothing being written to the file.  pFile = fopen("C:\contacts.txt", "w+"); is the correct way to do this by my understanding.

Comment: Same issue as the answer given to your previous question, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8231373/583044. Extra unnecessary break statements.

Comment: your wrong... try again.. Same code different question.

Comment: use switch case statements instead of if to reduce the unnecessary cluttering and unreadability. `switch(choice){case 1: fprintf(stdout, ... break; case2: and so on}`... breaks are fine in switch but not in `if than else` clauses unless you want to break out of a loop... you might want to use `continue` here instead of break.

Comment: I got confused with the switch...case appearance of the code but the reason it doesn't write to the file is the return 0; in the exit path.

Comment: And the path to your file is in correct, it should be "C:\\contacts.txt", assuming you have write permissions to the root of the C: drive. Note the double slash.

Comment: The path is C:\\ etc. and i do have write permissions. What should I change the return 0 to??

Comment: If you just want to exit the loop and continue with your fwrite() call then you should replace `return 0;` with `break;`. You probably also want to remove all the `break;` lines from the other if {} blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
while (choice == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4){
```

to:

```
while (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4){
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 4){
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `choice == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4` will always evaluate to true

choice == 1 evaluates to 1 if choice is 1 (true) otherwise to 0 (false)
2,3 and 4 evaluate to true if you do a logical or (||)
it will result in

```
false || true || true || true -> true
```

what you mean is probably

```
choice >= 1 && choice <= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax mistakes

```
choice == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4
```

should be

```
choice == 1 || choice ==  2 || choice ==  3 || choice == 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (choice == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4)
```

Is the same as saying

```
while (choice == 1 || TRUE == 2 || TRUE == 3 || TRUE == 4)
```